# Elasticsearch groovy token

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have in elasticsearch documents like this:

```
{
  "user_id": 295,
  "pictures": [
    {"type_id": 201201, "picture_id": 543},
    {"type_id": 201202, "picture_id": 544}
  ]
}
```

With a purpose to find users with specific picture type I run this query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9201/z/u/_search -d '{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['"'"'pictures.type_id'"'"'].values.contains(201201L)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

And it works perfectly! But when I run this query:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9201/z/u/_search -d '{
  "post_filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "doc['"'"'pictures.type_id'"'"'].values.contains(201201)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

it won't work, the difference between queries is `201201L and 201201`.

Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `201201L`, the `L` after the number denotes the fact that it is of type `Long`. Without the `L`, the number is of type `Integer` by default. This is a Java convention.

So if the type of `pictures.type_id` in your mapping is `long` then you need to compare it against a Long value, not an Integer one. The comparison in the `Long.equals()` method (which `List.contains()` calls internally) first checks that the argument is of type `Long`, if that's not the case, then the comparison fails.